# Flutter and Firestore! Set a Collection, a document and a field

Tags: flutter

I initalize a instance of my FireStore.Collection:

```
final Firestore store = Firestore.instance;
```

Now if i press on a Button, i wanted to add to the database a new Collection with a new document and some fields inside. At this time i only can choose a existing Collection and add a field to this collection. The Document is written automatic but i wanted to give it a name.
The Code:

```
onPressed: (){
                    store.runTransaction((Transaction transaction)async{
                      store.collection("test@test.de").add({"flutter":"awesome"});
                    });
                    print("Absenden");
                  },
```

How can i do this? 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify your document name inside document reference and call setData instead like below.

```
store.collection("test@test.de").document("documentName").setData({"flutter":"awesome"}); });
```